# Example in Chapter 2 of Rudin text

Tags: general-topology

In chapter 2 (Basic Topology) of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, he gives an example:

Let $A$ be the set of real numbers $x$ such that $0 < x \leq 1$. For every  $x \in A$, let $E_x$ be the set of real numbers y such that $0 < y < x$. Then (iii) $\bigcap_{x\in A} E_x$ is empty.

Can someone please explain why this is true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say that  $$I=\bigcap_{x\in A} E_x.$$

$I$ is the intersection of *all* the $E_x$.

That means that it contains some number $q$ if and only if $q$ is in *every* one of the $E_x$; that's what an intersection is.

Conversely, if some number $q$ is not in *every* one of the $E_x$, it is not in their intersection $I$.

But $q$ is *not* in $E_q$, so it is not in $I$.

This argument works for any $q$ at all, so this shows that *every* number $q$ is not in $I$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense. Much clearer than the one-liner included in the text.

Comment: If you're going to use Rudin, you need to learn to extrapolate this kind of thing from the one-liner in the text. To work through Rudin, you should have paper and pencil handy.  You read a sentence, then spend a few minutes working out why it is true.  Then you go on to the next sentence. If you try to read it like a novel, you will not have a happy time.

Comment: Thank you. I'm slowly learning that as I go through the text and also go through some lectures online.